# How store and retrieve dynamically added images from SQL lite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

How to store and retrieve these dynamically added images from the SQLlite database in Fragmnet

```
 addItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageView=new ImageView(getActivity());
                imageView.setImageResource(items[k]);
                itemId++;
                addView(imageView);
         }
        });

public void addView(ImageView imageView) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        imageView.setPadding(10,0,10,0);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        layout.addView(imageView);
    }
```

Comment: It will be useful to share the problem you want to solve in detail.

Comment: The problem is when I close the app, the dynamically added images are cleared. So I thought to store that images in the database and load it when the app opens

Comment: this sample : https://abhiandroid.com/database/add-retrieve-image-sqlite-database-example-android-studio.html